# How does $(k+1)!(k+2)(k+1)$ simplify to $(k+2)!(k+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, factorial

If $$n!=n(n-1)!$$ then $$(k+1)!= (k+1)k(k-1)!$$

and $$(k+2)!$$ would be $$(k+2)(k+1)k(k-1)!$$ or $$(k+2)(k+1)!$$
but what does the extra (k+1) do to make it (k+2)!(k+1)

Comment: $(k+2)! = (k+2)(k+1)!$, following the recursive definition of the factorial as $n! = n(n-1)!$.

Comment: $(k+2)! = (k+2)(k+1)!$, but where does the extra $(k+1)$ come from to make it $(k+2)!(k+1) = (k+1)!(k+2)(k+1)$?

Comment: It doesn't do any thing.  If you have $M = N$ then $M\cdot\text{Muriel the dancing fruitfly} = N \cdot \text{Muriel the dancing fruitfly}$.  So if $(k+1)!(k+2) = (k+2)!$ then $(k+1)!(k+2)\times (k+1) = (k+2)!\times (k+1)$.  That's all it is. It doesn't *mean* anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$5! = 5\times4\times3\times2\times1$$
But then:
$$4! = 4\times3\times2\times1\implies 5 !=5\times 4!$$
So by the same logic
$$(k+2)!=(k+2)(k+1)!$$

Comment: you mean $(k+2)!(k+1)$, right?

Answer (score 0):

$(k+1)!(k+2) = (k+2)!$, as explained in your question

$(k+1)!(k+2)(k+1) = (k+2)!(k+1)$ follows, by multiplying both sides by $(k+1)$.

You can always multiply both sides of a true equation by the same thing to obtain another true equation. You can also do anything else to both sides of an equation.

Answer (score 0):

$(K+2)!= (k+1)!(k+2)$

so $(k+1)!(k+1)(k+2)= (k+2)!(k+1)$